# Removing an element from the DataGridView.DataSource error

Tags: c#

I have a Windows Form application that has a `DataGridView` control with a `List` DataSource.
I must remove some elements from the DataGridView and I use the list to do that like this:

```
MyList.Remove(SpecificItem);
MyDataGridView.Invalidate(true);
MyDataGridView.Refresh();
```

And when I want to scroll all the way down to the last item in the `DataGridView` I get the `IndexOutOfRange` error. Even if I call the `MyDataGridView.Update();` I still get the same error. 
How can I get around this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since `MyDataGridView.DataSource` is not bound to the `List` you need to set the `MyDataGridView.DataSource`each time the `List` changes. Using `Invalidate()` or `Refresh()` doesn't do anything in this case.
This msdn link [Bind Data to the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx) might help you to bind your data to the `DataGridView`